# pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf() not saving attributes (metadata)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata, hdf5

Is there a way to preserve the attributes of a pandas DataFrame when saving it to an hdf5 file? I would like to store metadata alongside a pandas DataFrame in an hdf5 file.

Here is some simple code that shows the problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['data1'])
df.attrs.update({'test1':0,'test2':'this is a string'})
df.to_hdf('test.h5',key='df',complevel=9)
df_read = pd.read_hdf('test.h5')
df_read.attrs # this is an empty dict {} instead of what I created above
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HDFStore to save the metadata:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['data1'])
df.attrs.update({'test1':0,'test2':'this is a string'})

# Save file
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as hdf_store:
   hdf_store.put('data', df, format='table')
   hdf_store.get_storer('data').attrs.metadata = df.attrs


# Load file and meta
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as hdf_store:
   metadata = hdf_store.get_storer('data').attrs.metadata
   df_read = hdf_store.get('data')
   # If you want to set up meta in the df again
   df_read.attrs.update(metadata)
```

Answer (score 0):

When saving a Pandas DataFrame to an HDF5 file, the default behavior is to save only the data without preserving the attributes and metadata associated with the DataFrame. However, you can use the format='table' option to save the DataFrame as a PyTables table which supports storing metadata.

Here's an updated version of the code with the attributes preserved:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['data1'])
df.attrs.update({'test1': 0, 'test2': 'this is a string'})

# Save DataFrame with attributes using 'table' format
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
store.put('df', df, format='table', complevel=9)
store.close()

# Read DataFrame with attributes
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
df_read = store['df']
store.close()

print(df_read.attrs)  # Output: {'test1': 0, 'test2': 'this is a string'}
```

This code uses the pd.HDFStore class to create and manage HDF5 files. If you specify format='table' when saving the DataFrame , the attributes will be preserved with the data. When reading a DataFrame back from an HDF5 file, the attributes are accessible via df_read.attrs and contain the previously set values.

Note that using the "table" format may require additional dependencies such as pytables and numexpr. You can install it using pip install tables or pip install numexpr if you prefer.